# Google MapView Invalid child element

Tags: android, xamarin.android

Layout element  is uderlined blue as invalid child element in VS2010. Have reference to Mono.Android.GoogleMaps library.
How to get rid of that warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to ignore that as the project should still build correctly. The "intellisense" for layout files is just done through an XML schema (hence the axml extension, to distinguish it from other XML files). I'm guessing that the provided schema doesn't include the Map element.

The best check for seeing if your resource files are valid is building the project, since that's when they're run through the Android resource tools.